# To save user info on the same page by form submiting

Tags: users

I've searched and seen several questions and answers similar to this one , but all of them don't work for me.
Please help me with correct answer! Thanks you!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['info_submit'])){
        $user->data->user_nicename = $_POST['user_first_name'].'-'.$_POST['user_last_name'];
        $user->data->display_name = $_POST['user_first_name'].'-'.$_POST['user_last_name'];
        $user->data->user_email = esc_attr( $_POST['user_email'] );
        wp_update_user($user);

        update_user_meta($user_id , 'user_firstname' , $_POST['user_first_name']);
        update_user_meta($user_id , 'user_lastname' , $_POST['user_last_name']);

    }
?>
<form class="" name="info_form" id="info_form" action="" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-input">
            <label for="user_email">Email</label>
            <input required type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="<?php echo get_userdata($user_id)->user_email;?>" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <label for="user_first_name">First Name</label>
            <input required type="text" name="user_first_name" id="user_first_name" value="<?php echo get_userdata($user_id)->user_firstname;?>" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <label for="user_last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input required type="text" name="user_last_name" id="user_last_name" value="<?php echo get_userdata($user_id)->user_lastname;?>" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <label for="user_display_name">Display Name</label>
            <input required type="text" name="user_display_name" id="user_display_name" value="<?php echo get_userdata($user_id)->display_name;?>" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="info_submit" id="info_submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should add the page url (don't hard-code it) under the form "action" attribute.

So assuming you have access to the_permalink(), you should do the following:

```
action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
```

Check if that saves into the $_POST array by adding the following somewhere in that file and try submitting the form:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
```